# how to create read only text ctrl but support copy paste event

Tags: python, wxpython

In my application i have text control.
I want my text ctrl should be read only but when some one right click on this he is able to copy the value from that ctrl and he can paste that value in other text control.

If i made my text control read only with wx.TE_READONLY then copy/paste is not working.

Is there any requirement to handle other type of wx event or i have to set more type of wx style flags while creating the text control object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you use a static text instead of a readonly TextCtrl?  That might work.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm Im on windows 7 and  don't have any problem copying from a `textCtrl` that has the `wx.READ_ONLY` style flag set.

You said you wanted to paste into another `textCtrl` -obviously you can't have the `wx.READ_ONLY` style flag set in the `textCtrl` you want to be able to paste into.

Try out the demo below, you should be able to copy from the textCtrl on the left(which is read only) to the one on the right(which doesn't have the read only style set).

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=-1):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id, size=(200,200))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self,wx.ID_ANY)     
        bsizer = wx.BoxSizer()       
        read_only_txtCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,
                        "This textCtrl is read only",
                        style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY)

        editable_txtCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,
                        "This textCtrl is editable",
                        style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        bsizer.Add(read_only_txtCtrl, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        bsizer.Add(editable_txtCtrl, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(bsizer)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MainWindow(None)
    frame.SetSize((200,200))
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

We should bind wx.EVT_TEXT_COPY and wx.EVT_TEXT_PASTE with text control.
one can copy and paste data from text ctrl although text ctrl is read only mode.

Comment: What, have you read my answer at all? Why do  do you need to bind to  `wx.EVT_TEXT_COPY` and `wx.EVT_TEXT_PASTE`? Have you run the runnable sample I provided with my answer?

Comment: @volting i got your point, even i run that one. But here in u r running sample one text ctrl you cannot copy the value from other.I need both the text ctrl should be readonly and support copy and paste. Sorry for if i was not put the requirement clearly. Anyway thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Seems like a catch 22 you want your textBox to be read only yet you want to edit it i.e paste into it.

Comment: @volting: Its no sort of catch 22. actually i just want to avoid error input in text ctrl, because i am writing right input first, so some one want to copy that value in other text ctrl can only copy that value and paste but cannot edit in text ctrl. Its possbile if you discard EVT_TEXT and use EVT_TEXT_COPY and EVT_TEXT_PASTE.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had the same challenge. I needed a textbox where users could paste information (or open -> read file via a menu). The app would then analyze the info for correctness. But I didn't want to allow editing in the textbox - it would suggest that you could correct in the same textbox, while the app was for analysis only. Yeah, requirements, I know.

Weird thing was, I could make a readonly TextCtrl under MacOSX that would allow pasting (but not editing), but not on Windows.

In order to support both, I ended up creating a read/writesuper(MyWin, self).**init**(None, size=(800,600)) textbox (to allow pasting under windows) and binding wx.EVT_TEXT events to it (apart from wx.EVT_TEXT_PASTE for the obvious pasting). The EVT_TEXT handler that's triggered when the textctrl's contents change, simply shows a dialog that you aren't allowed to do this.

In the app a boolean this.painted plays the following role: when this.painted is true, then modifications of the textctrl aren't allowed. So, the onpaste handler first sets this.painted to false, then modifies the TextCtrl's contents, then sets this.painted to true (otherwise the dialog alert would also go off during the paste event, which I wanted to allow). Unfortunately when the EVT_TEXT handler goes off, the window's contents have already been modified by a user hitting some key. Therefore the app also needs a backup buffer to put back into the TextCtrl when such editing has been detected.

According to the Python docs, TextCtrl.ChangeValue() instead of SetValue() should not trigger the EVT_TEXT event (which would be handy) but I couldn't get that to work, might be my mistake due to not-enough-time-to-investigate-because-it-should-have-been-done-yesterday.

Not an elegant solution, but works.

```
import wx

class MyWin(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWin, self).__init__(None, size=(800,600))
        self.painted = True
        self.backup = ''
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.HSCROLL)
        self.text.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_PASTE, self.onpaste)
        self.text.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.ontextchange)
        self.Show()

    def onpaste(self, event):
        if not wx.TheClipboard.IsOpened():
            buf = wx.TextDataObject()
            wx.TheClipboard.Open()
            success = wx.TheClipboard.GetData(buf)
            wx.TheClipboard.Close()
            if success:
                self.painted = False
                self.backup = buf.GetText()
                self.text.SetValue(self.backup)
                self.painted = True

    def ontextchange(self, event):
        if self.painted:
            dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, 'Editing not allowed', '', wx.OK)
            dlg.ShowModal()
            dlg.Destroy()
            self.painted = False
            self.text.SetValue(self.backup)
            self.painted = True


app = wx.App()
frame = MyWin()
app.MainLoop()
```